# In C# MangementObjectSeacher I am not able to use Query.QueryString and Get()

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, process

This is my code, and i am getting problem with mos.Query and Get().Even after adding System.Management Namespace.

```
string processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher();

mos.Query.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" + processName + @"'";

if (mos.Get().Count > 1)
{
     return true;
}
else
{
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. A more detailed description of your problem would help. In the meantime i would also suggest you to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

When I restructure your code, I only ever receive one result, so your code would always return false, unless you have multiple instances of the same app with the same image name running.

```
        var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;
        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher();
        mos.Query.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" + processName + @"'";

        var collection = mos.Get();
        var count = collection.Count;

        // If count == 1, the process is already running.  If it's 0, it's not running.  If it's > 1, then multiple copies are running.
        return count == 1;
```

You may also want to do some reading on Mutex and Single Instance applications.  There are many good tutorials here and elsewhere on the subject.

Comment: Actually i am trying to check whether my app is already running or not.?

Comment: Then you probably want to check if the .Count property >= 1, not > 1.  Or if you are trying to create a single instance, check .Count == 1.